# How do I change the color of some text on a button I made from a menu item on a wordpress header using css?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the Ocean WP theme and I am also using the WP job manager plugin. On the header there is an option on the menu called "post a job" and I wanted to turn it into a button.

I found some information online and I managed to turn it into a button as so: http://prntscr.com/pi6zec

I made some changes in the custom css section: prntscr.com/pie2hz

But I want to change the color of the text to white so it can be seen more clearly next to the green. Does anybody know how I can change it? I tried:

text-emphasis-color

and

text-decoration-color

...but they did not do anything, not that I could see anyway, does anyone know how I could change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code to your CSS file

```
body #menu-item-840 a{
    color:#fff!important;
}
```